# Should age, religion, gender or any other personal information be edited/omitted out of questions?

Tags: discussion

Should questions where the questionnaire is telling their age, religion, gender or any other personal information be edited to remove thier personal information?

For example :

1. I am 14 year old and I
   did ....
2. I am a girl and did
   this....
3. I am a Muslim, I am
   having doubts....
4. I am a non-muslim and
   would like to
   know....

Comment: Not easy to answer it looks to me like a case by case decision!

Comment: @Medi1Saif we don't need 
to make a "for boys" and "for girls" section, both the ruling of boys and girl should be mentioned in one place/answer. I think questionaire age/iman/religion doesn't add anything useful to the question also this site isn't for preaching islam.

Comment: First of all for us as moderators it is an issue if an underage person posts here! As we must report that! The age usually is not significant for a rule it is the maturity which counts! But the gender might be more significant. So the personal information shared can be removed by any editor of a post however stackexchange policies must be respected. Let's say a person reported about something he/she has done in his/her youth is different than a 13 years person saying I have done such and such!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some rulings will differ depending on the person's age, gender, etc, so if it's relevant to the question, then it should be included so a proper answer can be given. Anything that's not relevant to the question is just noise and should be removed.

However, it really shouldn't matter if the question is asked *by*, say, a 12-year old girl, or by a guardian on behalf of a 12-year old girl, or just a scholar studying the effects of rulings on 12-year old girls. The answer would mostly be the same, so even if the details are kept in the question they should probably be abstracted out so as to not identify the questionasker themselves.

In addition, an ideal question is useful to more than just one person. Whenever possible, questions should be generalized so as to be more useful to a wider future audience. Unless there's a reason to believe that the ruling is *different* for, say, a 12-year old girl compared to an 11-year old girl, the exact age is probably irrelevant, whereas the ruling between a mature adult and a child *would* probably be very different.

So, for example, instead of "I am a 12-year old girl and I have a question…", maybe "What is the ruling for a Muslim female below the age of accountability?" would be better.

If a question is super specific such that the exact personal details of the questionasker are all relevant and can't be generalized, it's very likely the type of personal advice or fatwa question which we should be discouraging anyway, and should probably just be closed.

---

On a tangential note, if someone *does* provide personal details indicating that they are below the age of 16, that should be flagged for moderator attention even if the identifying details are edited out. See also: [What are our policies regarding underage users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355419/132874)

Comment: Well answered but I think user's age and gender overshadowed user's religion... Kindly aprise your thoughts on user's religion aswell.

Comment: @AbduRahman I don't think there's any difference between age, gender, religion, nationality, race, shoe size, or any other personal details one might choose to reveal: If it matters to the question, keep it. Otherwise, it's noise.